# Microsoft C# Compiler error with no error description

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I pretty new to Unity (I started today) and anytime I open a project I get a compiler error

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

In my project. Every time I open my project it asks me to take me to safe mode and there (in the safe mode) there are two error in the photo below

[image: Error Image]

I searched the web but everyone having this error had a tip or description telling them what might be wrong, but I didn't got that.

I have created no C# scripts in my projects. I also tried deleting the library folder but it didn't work. Also the  error has only the description given in the photo. I am using Unity Editor Version 2020.3.20f1

Also is there a C# compiler which I need to install like we do in Java and C++, because if that's the case I have not installed any C# compiler in my system.

If anyone could even tell me the meaning of this error I will be grateful

Edit #1

I have realized that the latest .NET Framework is already in my system, so there is no case of .NET framework not installed

Edit #2

I checked my compiler settings and these are the configurations
(The API Compatibility Level was set to .NET Standard 2.0 I changed it to .NET 4.x)

[image: Compiler Settings]

But when built the project, I got the following errors which could describe more of my situation
(Note : The errors were same in the case of .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.x)

[image: NEW ERROR - 1]
[image: NEW ERROR - 1]
[image: NEW ERROR - 1]

The

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

error has the same description after everything.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the .NET SDK installed?

Comment: I didn't had the .NET SDK installed, I installed it but it didn't solve the issue I am still having the same issue, but Thank You

Comment: I am sorry but it is showing nothing on hovering the mouse on it, the only description I get is shown in the bottom of the picture , "Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @frankhermes I am using Unity Hub 3.0.0-beta.5 with Unity Editor Version 2020.3.20f1. Moreover I am using the Personal (free) version of Unity

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed Visual studio through the Unity Hub, everything needed for Unity development should be installed correctly with nothing else to be done. My experience with this error is usually when i import an external package/ any dll into Unity, with the editor open. The error gets thrown immediately and a simple editor restart usually fixes it. If you haven't done this, I'd recommend you try 2 things:

1. Go to Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings and look at your compiler and .NET version settings.
2. Check your package manager to see if any packages are installed that may be causing the issue. Unity 2020+ generally installs some extra packages by default (like Unity Collab, etc), although this is unlikely to cause this problem

Comment: I did not install Visual Studio through Unity Hub it was already installed in my system, (I chose the Visual Studio for Game Development package during installation of Visual Studio). I tried checking my compiler and what I got is in the Edit #2 of the question, please check. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: I'd recommend a fresh install of visual studio through unity hub after uninstalling the existing one. I have tried linking an existing installed visual studio with unity before (especially after Unity hub came) and it almost always seems to act up in one way or another.

Comment: Tried that, did the whole process again but, it turns out that after 3 hours the error is the same

Comment: "Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings and look at your compiler and .NET version settings."  Where does one find the Build Settings?